# SQL Query to pull data from Excel 2016 using Openrowset - Getting syntax error

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, openrowset

This query is giving me a syntax error near the comma at the end of the file location, right before the .  Can anyone please tell me why?  I've searched to no avail.  I'm using SQL Server 2014 Express and Excel 2016.

Thanks

```
INSERT INTO Simply_Capitation_Lineal (uniqueid, mos, groupid, GroupName, mos2, QnxMemID, dob, age, 
sex, mname, CapRateID, CapTermID, CapEffDate, CapAmount, CapAffID, PCPProvid, PCPFullName, PayToAffID, 
PayToProvid, PayToName, CapDate, PlanID, MedicareID, Simple_County, [cover&OME], Triangle_Cover, 
CarrierMemberID, CheckNumber)
SELECT uniqueid, mos, groupid, GroupName, mos2, QnxMemID, dob, age, 
sex, mname, CapRateID, CapTermID, CapEffDate, CapAmount, CapAffID, PCPProvid, PCPFullName, PayToAffID, 
PayToProvid, PayToName, CapDate, PlanID, MedicareID, Simple_County, [cover&OME], Triangle_Cover, 
CarrierMemberID, CheckNumber
FROM OPENROWSET('MSDASQL',
                'driver=IMAHQ12\sqlexpress',
                'excel 12.0 xml; Database=C:\Users\td\Dropbox (IMA Team)\IMA Utilization Reports\DB\201605\Simply\Capitation Lineal - INHEALTH MD ALLIANCE LLC - MSO - FINANCE - 2016.04.xlsx','SELECT * FROM [Detail$]')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.  This wasn't the actual fix but it helped me find the problem.  The second comma (after the driver) should be a semicolon.  Here is the corrected query:

select * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'excel 12.0;HDR=yes;imex=1;driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)}; extended properties=excel 12.0 xml; Database=C:\Users\td\Utilization Reports\DB\201605\Simply\Capitation Lineal - INHEALTH MD ALLIANCE LLC - MSO - FINANCE - 2016.04.xlsx', 'select * from [Detail$]')

Comment: It then gave me the error "Could not find installable ISAM.  This site was the answer:  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/209805

Answer (score 0):

Consider using an Excel compliant driver:

```
...
SELECT * FROM
OPENROWSET('MSDASQL','DRIVER={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};
     DBQ=C:\Users\td\Dropbox (IMA Team)\IMA Utilization Reports\DB\201605\Simply\Capitation Lineal - INHEALTH MD ALLIANCE LLC - MSO - FINANCE - 2016.04.xlsx', 
     'SELECT * FROM [Detail$]')
```

Alternatively, you can use a provider version:

```
SELECT * FROM
OPENDATASOURCE('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
   'Data Source=C:\Users\td\Dropbox (IMA Team)\IMA Utilization Reports\DB\201605\Simply\Capitation Lineal - INHEALTH MD ALLIANCE LLC - MSO - FINANCE - 2016.04.xlsx;Extended Properties=Excel 12.0')
   ...Detail$
```

Comment: why would someone mark this down and not comment. It is correct.

Comment: Thanks @MEdwin, if incorrect, I would have changed code or deleted it!